# Netbeans - Needs to be compiled badge

Tags: java, netbeans

I made a new class in Netbeans, and it has a little wrench icon on it that says "needs to be compiled" when I mouse-over.

How do I get rid of that?  I've trying everything, compiling the file, compiling the package, cleaning and building the project.

(I'm on Netbeans 6.7.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `File > Project Properties > Build > Compiling`, check *Compile on Save*.

Comment: why is this warning happening?

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz: I think I've seen it when I open a clean project, i.e. one with no class files in `build/classes`.